# how to wear multiple blades? does it matter?

Tags: medieval, tools, daily-life, swords, aesthetics

both are quite easy to animate, no further programming required except switching secondary sword attachment from side_hip1.r to side_hip2.l so it's mostly about aesthetics now... which is a problem since to me both look good.

So let's make it about which one is more practical in daily life, like if you had instead of two war sword... make two small self-defense swords or knives or hatchets which can easily be used for various things on a daily basis.

Then does the placement of the "tools" matter at all? I tried replicating it in real life and both ways seem uncofortable when running or doing quick movements, the only difference, is that I can hold to stabilize both handles at the same time with one hand, if they are one the same hip, so when running... I can stabilize them with one arm and use the other arm to run.

any other significant difference?

[image]

Comment: +1 for doing actual in person Worldbuilding research! Question: especially in light of L Dutch's samurai example, have you accounted for the harness rig itself as a factor (i.e., kind of loose and dangly in the lady knight's example, vs held still and close to the body, almost more on the waist, in sir samurai's example)? Also another question: have you considered Backpack Syndrome? Taking note that school children who sling heavy backpacks on one side tend to develop problems that school kids and hikers who evenly distribute weight don't suffer from.

Comment: Is the intent to dual-wield? If so, are we looking at matching weapons, or an main weapon and companion weapon? If not, what purpose is there to having multiple weapons? Backups are great, but backups of that size are not very practical for multiple reasons.

Comment: i ain't no swordmaster but nobody draw a sword from their waist especially long sword️

Comment: @user6760 where are you supposed to draw a longsword from other than your hips? it's the only practical and feasible way

Comment: Very carefully.

Comment: FWIW, Shad, from his Shadiversity channel, did an interesting video on [how many weapons one could carry comfortably](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9BqK-nq60A) including him suiting up with his loadout.

Comment: @elemtilas Just a quick note on the lady knight's harness: With a third strap, properly adjusted, around each leg, I think one could eliminate a lot of the swords' floppage without restricting movement too much.

Comment: @elutionary -- Actually, I think that would be rather uncomfortable and unwieldy.  I also think it would restrict movement. Strapping something relatively snugly around a girl's upper thigh will almost assuredly result in it slipping down to where her thighs aren't so wide. She'd end up with the same problem, plus the binding and twisting of the loose straps. I also think the way she's got her swords angled is going to cause problems when she's running and deffo when she wants to sit down!

Comment: I think you underestimate the importance of your casual mention of "daily life". You wouldn't wear the same attire and same weapons if you're going to battle in the middle of a war than if you're going to buy groceries and just want to be able to defend yourself if attacked. Everything is a compromise. Weapons are heavy. If running for your life must be an option you will carry fewer and lighter weapons than if you're planning to fight to the death. I suspect any serious and wealthy warrior would have several different sets of armour and weapons for different uses.

Comment: @user6760 Nope, a cross-draw from the hip is the norm for almost any one-handed bladed weapon above a certain size. It’s significantly less awkward than drawing over the shoulder or from the same side, and lets you attack immediately as you’re drawing.

Answer (score 18):

This is an historical photo of a real samurai, who were famous for carrying two swords, the katana, with a longer blade, and the wakizashi, with a shorter blade:

[image]

More than aesthetics it's a matter of practicality to dictate where to carry the swords.

Considering that one normally would use the dominant hand to pull out the sword, because in a fight you don't want to fumble with the weakest hand since every moment count.

Therefore it makes sense to carry both swords on the same side, the opposite one with respect to the dominant hand, which in the majority of the people means carrying the swords on the left side.

Comment: Upvoted, but if both blades are short-ish *and* the user may need to use a bow then better to position the weapon-carrying rig on the dominant side, otherwise the hilts may foul the bowstring when drawing an arrow back (hence quivers are normallly on the dominant side).  There's a Lindybeige video where he demonstrates that it's quite practical to draw even a moderately long blade from a scabbard attached quite high to the belt on the same side as the arm drawing it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94c88HfACfQ

Comment: In Samurai culture aesthetics, tradition and also laws played a big role in their attire. E.g. in the Edo-Period it was required for Samurai to wear their sword pair visibly as a symbol of status. So while it was at least somewhat practical, it is not like radical practicality was the discerning factor when looking at samurai (or at european kights for that matter) - they were nobility first and warrior second.

Answer (score 14):

- Are the two blades drawn and used at the same time? I'm thinking of the [main-gauche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrying_dagger) to go with one-handed swords. If so, different sides, but then one blade might be much shorter.
- Are both blades long enough that it requires a [baldric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldric) for practical handling? Baldrics on both sides would cross each other awkwardly.

Comment: Crossing baldrics are actually a thing. I see images of drummers that have them, though I can't say how well that would work with swords.

Answer (score 7):

It mostly depends on usage.

- If both blades are supposed to be used together, one in each hand, then it makes sense to have two different blades (e.g.: sword and misericorde) in two different positions (normal left for sword, assuming right handed wielder, and front/right belt for stiletto).
- If blades are used for different purposes (e.g.: katana and wakizashi) then they are worn on the (approximately) same position (note Japanese samurai *always* wore them on left side, even if left-handed).
- If blades are long enough it may be expedient to wear them on back (Gerald of Rivia style).

It is difficult to answer without knowing context.

Comment: Wearing a sword strapped to your back is only really practical for traveling, it's extremely awkward to unsheathe anything longer than a single arms length from your back (since the tip will still be in the sheath at full arm extension, unlike a waist sheath where you have nearly the full length of torso+arm)

Comment: @DBS: Again it all depends on details of usage and blade details. Japanese nodachi (way longer than a katana) were usually worn on back because their curved blade made unsheathing possible *and*, being used mainly in the battlefield, it wasn't usually needed to fast draw (iaido style)

Answer (score 4):

A configuration that makes sense to me if its a longer and shorter blade is the longer one on the side, and the shorter one near the small of your back, with the pommel facing your off-hand for quickly grabbing for dual wielding.[image: dagger or short blade along small of back]

this is good for stealth and quick drawing, as well as being able to pull this one as a defensive weapon.